# What is snap exactly?

Tags: 18.04, snap

So I was hunting for disk space, and found those files in /var/lib/snapd/snaps, which picked my interest:

```
-rw------- 1 root 157M sty  4 04:56 gnome-3-28-1804_110.snap
-rw------- 1 root 161M sty 25 16:45 gnome-3-28-1804_116.snap
-rw------- 2 root 243M kwi 28 00:56 gnome-3-34-1804_27.snap
-rw------- 1 root 256M maj  9 04:02 gnome-3-34-1804_33.snap
```

what are those exactly? I suppose some kind of snap images, but how do I use them, or am I already using them? Those seem like gnome versions, my gnome-shell shows this:

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.4
```

There seems to be version 3.34 in that snap dir, but how can I use this?

Comment: These are libraries for GNOME Snaps. 110, 116, 27 and 33 are revision/versions.

Comment: So it appears that those are snap libraries, to remove those and reclaim some of your /var space use the following commands:
`sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd`
`sudo apt remove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap`
`rm -rf ~/snap`

This will get rid of entire snap subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Snap is a package manager developed by Canonical, which maintains Ubuntu, which provides self-contained applications that run in a sandbox.

There are pros and cons to snap, which you can look up elsewhere, but you have stumbled upon one of the downsides to it, which is that it has a much larger burden of disk space than traditionally-installed applications, which link to shared libraries and thus, when you install many of them, have a lot of shared code in common. The snap packages contain all dependencies within the package itself. This makes them take up more disk space, more memory to run, and also makes them slower to install and slower to load, and they usually run substantially slower too.

The packages you are asking about specifically, in this question, are the GNOME 3.28 and 3.34 stacks, shared base libraries and desktop integration components. Canonical has even started using snaps for library components of the operating system, as you have seen. Even if your shell is using 3.28, version 3.34 might be installed for some other app that needs it so I would not remove it unless you are sure nothing depends on it.

If you are concerned about disk space and efficiency, rather than micromanage these packages, your best bet may be to change distributions. Canonical has moved deep into the snap package framework, leaning more heavily on it with each passing year, moving progressive more and more components of the OS into it, as you are finding in your example here. If you are happy with the speed, performance, and memory / disk space utilization of your OS, then great, just leave these be. But if you are thinking about wanting to clear up this amount of disk space because you care about it, you would probably be better served by some other distro such as Arch, which avoids these types of packages by default (although it allows you to choose to install the package managers and then install specific packages if you want). Mint, another popular distro, is not appreciably different than Ubuntu in this regard because it has similarly moved to flatpak, which is a more-or-less similar package system. It is only for desktop components, not shared libraries or core components of the operating system, so it could perhaps be a "middle ground" of avoiding setups like you see here, with the shared GNOME stack installed as a snap, but while still using flatpak for a lot of Desktop applications. Keep in mind, the effect is going to be small because either of these packages is going to have a lot of bloat installed in large desktop apps, which take up a huge portion of the binaries on your system and, on a desktop, are the ones you open most frequently, stuff like web browsers.

Answer (score -1):

The snap command gathers system configuration information and compresses the information into a pax file. The file may then be written to a device such as tape or DVD, or transmitted to a remote system. The information gathered with the snap command might be required to identify and resolve system problems.